# In ETAS INCA, is there a way to quickly retrieve an item from an arbitrary path in an ASAP2Project?

Tags: .net, extension-methods, calibration

I'm trying to connect to INCA through the .NET API in order to navigate the folder structure of an ASAP2 project.  Specifically, I want to get an object that represents the "Target" folder that I've highlighted below.

[image]

This is proving pretty tricky--The API provides a ton of classes that have the name "Folder" in them:  `Folder`, `Asap2ProjectFolder`, and `IncaFolder`.  So what do I need to know in order to retrieve the "Target" folder?

Answer (score 0):

Your first impulse might be to think of the Target folder as existing on a long path like `USER A\Demo\Demo03\Foo\Bar\Baz\Target`.  Unfortunately, INCA doesn't have a mechanism to do this--instead, you have to retrieve the lowest item in the **Database Objects** portion of the path, and then query that item for the **Datasets** portion of the path.

From the database root, we need to drill down to Demo03, which is an `Asap2Project`:

```
USER A\Demo\Demo03
```

From within Demo03, we then need to drill down to Target, which is an `Asap2ProjectFolder`:

```
Foo\Bar\Baz\Target
```

The first part is pretty simple--we can connect to INCA and get the Demo03 Asap2Project in just a few lines of code:

```
Asap2ProjectFolder targetFolder = null;
Inca myIncaInstance = new Inca();
DataBase myDB = myIncaInstance.GetCurrentDataBase();
DataBaseItem tempItem = myDB.GetItemInFolder("Demo03", "USER A\\Demo");

if ((tempItem != null) && 
    (tempItem.IsAsap2Project()))
   {
   Asap2Project demoProject = (Asap2Project)tempItem;

   // Next step: grab the "Target folder!"
   }
```

Now, here's where things get a bit tricky.

If we were trying to get a `DataSet` like Demo03_1, we could use a call like `demoProject.GetDataSetForName("Demo03\\Demo03_1")`.  The problem is, this method only works for objects of type DataSet.  So we can't use it to retrieve a folder like `Foo\Bar\Baz\Target`.  If you've poked around in the API a bit, you might have tried something like this:

```
Asap2ProjectFolder tempProjFolder = demoProject.GetTopFolderNamed("Foo");
tempItem = tempProjFolder.GetDataBaseItem("Bar\\Baz\\Target");  // Won't work.
tempItem = tempProjFolder.GetSubFolder("Bar\\Baz\\Target");     // This won't either.
```

Turns out that we need to be a bit more resourceful.  Let's make `GetItemInFolder()` extension methods for the `Asap2Project` and `Asap2ProjectFolder` classes, so those classes will have the same item-retrieval flexibility as the `DataBase` class:

```
namespace IncaExtensions
   {
   public static class GetItemInFolderExtensions
      {
      /// <summary>
      /// Gets a DataBaseItem from an Asap2Project in an arbitrary subfolder.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="project">The current Asap2Project</param>
      /// <param name="itemName">The name of the item that we want to retrieve</param>
      /// <param name="folderName">The path, delimited by backslashes ('\\')</param>
      /// <returns>A DataBaseItem matching the request.  
      /// If no matching item is found, or if the path is invalid, return null.
      /// </returns>
      public static DataBaseItem GetItemInFolder(this Asap2Project project, 
                                                 string itemName, 
                                                 string folderName)
         {
         DataBaseItem returnItem = null;

         if ((folderName != null) &&
             (itemName != null))
            {
            string folderToken = PluckPathToken(ref folderName);
            Asap2ProjectFolder subFolder = 
               project.GetTopFolderNamed(folderToken);

            if (subFolder != null)
               {
               returnItem = subFolder.GetItemInFolder(itemName, folderName); 
               }
            }

         return returnItem;
         }


      /// <summary>
      /// Recursive call that returns a DataBaseItem in the target path.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="folder">The Asap2ProjectFolder to drill down</param>
      /// <param name="itemName">The name of the item that we want to retrieve</param>
      /// <param name="folderName">The path, delimited by backslashes ('\\')</param>
      /// <returns>A DataBaseItem matching the request.  
      /// If no matching item is found, or if the path is invalid, return null.
      /// </returns>
      public static DataBaseItem GetItemInFolder(this Asap2ProjectFolder folder, 
                                                 string itemName, 
                                                 string folderName)
         {
         DataBaseItem returnItem = null;

         if ((folderName != null) &&
             (itemName != null))
            {
            string folderToken = PluckPathToken(ref folderName);
            Asap2ProjectFolder subFolder = 
               (Asap2ProjectFolder)folder.GetSubFolder(folderToken);

            if (subFolder != null)
               {
               returnItem = subFolder.GetItemInFolder(itemName, folderName);
               }
            }
         else
            {
            returnItem = folder.GetDataBaseItem(itemName);
            }

         return returnItem;
         }


      /// <summary>
      /// Removes a backslash-delimited token from a string and shortens the
      /// input string.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="folderName">Backslash-delimited path.  This will be 
      /// shortened each time a token is removed.</param>
      /// <returns>The latest path token</returns>
      static string PluckPathToken(ref string folderName)
         {
         int slashIdx = folderName.IndexOf('\\');

         // If folderName has path tokens, extract the first token and
         // shorten folderName accordingly.
         string folderToken = (slashIdx > -1) ? 
            folderName.Substring(0, slashIdx) : folderName;
         folderName = (slashIdx > -1) ? 
            folderName.Substring(slashIdx + 1) : null;

         return folderToken;
         }
      }
   }
```

This makes it super-easy to grab items out of an `Asap2Project` or `Asap2ProjectFolder`.  To grab the Target folder, we only need the following calls:

```
using IncaExtensions;
...
Asap2ProjectFolder targetFolder = null;
Inca myIncaInstance = new Inca();
DataBase myDB = myIncaInstance.GetCurrentDataBase();
DataBaseItem tempItem = myDB.GetItemInFolder("Demo03", "USER A\\Demo");

if ((tempItem != null) && 
    (tempItem.IsAsap2Project()))
   {
   Asap2Project demoProject = (Asap2Project)tempItem;
   targetFolder = (Asap2ProjectFolder)demoProject.GetItemInFolder("Target", "Foo\\Bar\\Baz");
   }
```

Comment: I've created a Gist of the extension methods [here](https://gist.github.com/ThoughtProcess/6223426).